# how to solve "pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully." in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

When i try to install a set of packages in colab it is showing

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Installing backend dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I am trying to run a code from github. While running the programs's requirements, it is showing this error.